# laravel blade echo misplacement

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

From the little I understand of Laravel Im quite thrown off by whats happening.

[Browser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFUp5.png)

Blade template being loaded

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{{asset('/css/app.css')}}">
<a href='{{route("overview")}}'>Overview</a>
<a href='{{route("view", "Supplier")}}'>Suppliers</a>
<a href='{{route("view","resource")}}'>Resources</a>
<a href='{{route("view","price")}}'>Prices</a>
<a href='{{route("view","recipe")}}'>Reciepes</a>
<a href='{{route("add", $current)}}'>Add</a>
@if($modal)
<table>
<tr>
@foreach($modal->get_display_fields() as $e)
    <th> {{$e->label}} </th>
@endforeach
</tr>
@foreach($items as $item)
    {{$item->init_fields()}}
    @foreach($item->get_display_fields() as $q) 
        <tr>
        {{$q->value}}
        </tr>
    @endforeach

@endforeach
</table>
@endif
```

The intention is that a table is created with rows with each having a value printed into it

Comment: can you mention what is the expected behavior so we can help you

Comment: @DhavalChheda generate a bunch of rows with values inside a table. For some reason its being printed outside of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and lemme know if you face any issues

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{{asset('/css/app.css')}}">
<a href='{{route("overview")}}'>Overview</a>
<a href='{{route("view", "Supplier")}}'>Suppliers</a>
<a href='{{route("view","resource")}}'>Resources</a>
<a href='{{route("view","price")}}'>Prices</a>
<a href='{{route("view","recipe")}}'>Reciepes</a>
<a href='{{route("add", $current)}}'>Add</a>
@if($modal)
<table>
<tr>
@foreach($modal->get_display_fields() as $e)
    <th> {{$e->label}} </th>
@endforeach
</tr>
@foreach($items as $item)
    {{$item->init_fields()}}
    @foreach($item->get_display_fields() as $q) 
        <tr>
        <td>{{$q->value}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
</table>
@endif
```

Comment: It works, though I dont know why, and also, what about if I need to make multiple columns

Comment: it works because I have your $q->value inside a <td> which is the table cell and now if you want more columns then add more items to your <th> and then retrieve the values of the same in the $q fireach loop and you will have more columns

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer provided then you can click the check below the answer and upvote it if you like

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{{asset('/css/app.css')}}">
<a href='{{route("overview")}}'>Overview</a>
<a href='{{route("view", "Supplier")}}'>Suppliers</a>
<a href='{{route("view","resource")}}'>Resources</a>
<a href='{{route("view","price")}}'>Prices</a>
<a href='{{route("view","recipe")}}'>Reciepes</a>
<a href='{{route("add", $current)}}'>Add</a>
@if($modal)
<table>
<tr>
@foreach($modal->get_display_fields() as $e)
    <th> {{$e->label}} </th>
@endforeach
</tr>
@foreach($items as $item)
    {{$item->init_fields()}}
    @foreach($item->get_display_fields() as $q) 
        <tr>
           <td>{{$q->value}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
</table>
@endif
```

Comment: Display value inside the table data tag(td)